Intellisense is not working for Blade(PHP) files although VS Code is treating this file as Blade. How to resolve this issue?
I have been using laravel for doing some projects. But after opening the vs code, when I checked the blade.php files, there was no intellisense, but i checked the other php and css files, those are working nicely.

No intellisense in Laravel's Blade file.

How to solve this issue??

check your language mode in that file if is php and not like markdown/ plaintext (I check that on  VSC under and  in the right)
